# How to submit a form in Reactjs? (Form Submission)

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

**I am new to react, don't know too much about react or frontend.**

I am having some problem with my search function. First of all, when I comment out my FormControl my search function is not working. I am trying to use search with autocomplete.

```
<Form
  className="main_form"
  onSubmit={submitHandler}
  inline
  style={{ marginRight: 100 }}
>
  {/* <FormControl className="main_form"
    type="text"
    placeholder="Search for products"
    name='q'
    className="col-md-12 input"
    aria-label="Search"
    onChange={(e) => setKeyword(e.target.value)}
    
/> */}

  <Typeahead
    id="basic-typeahead-single"
    labelKey="name"
    onChange={setSingleSelections}
    options={products}
    placeholder="Search for products"
    selected={singleSelections}
  />

  <Button type="submit" variant="outline-primary" className="main-btn">
    <i class="fas fa-search" style={{ fontSize: 13 }}></i>
  </Button>
</Form>;
```

**This is my submithandler**

```
const submitHandler = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (Keyword) {
    history.push(`/?keyword=${Keyword}`);
  } else {
    history.push(history.push(history.location.pathname));
  }
};
```

I don't know where I did wrong. If I comment out Typeahead then my search is working without autosuggestion. I want both working perfectly.

Comment: So why don't you keep your `FormControl`?

Comment: How i can keep my formcontrol because my auto suggestion input box is Typeahead